# Efficient way to override spring repositories delete method for all repositories

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I want to modify the `repository.deleteAll()` and `repository.delete()` so it don't delete everything, but just set active column to false.

Is this achievable for all my repository at once ?

Comment: I really wouldn't do that. That would radically change the contract of these two methods. Why don't you just add two separate methods, with their own javadoc, their own contract, and their own implementation? http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories

Comment: Additional note: why do you even need a repository method to do that? How about just `myEntity.setActive(false)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data: Override save method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036159/spring-data-override-save-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean so-called 'soft delete'...
There is one of implementations: [Handling soft-deletes with Spring JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323557/handling-soft-deletes-with-spring-jpa)

And this issue is still open for Spring Data JPA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-307