# Spring Data MongoDB call original method in Custom Repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am writing a custom Mongo Repository. In it I am trying to override the default save method. The overriden save method will also call the original save method after doing some operations.

As per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48355583/5970352, I can inject the EntityManager.

But that is a Spring Data JPA specific thing, right? If I have to do the same in Spring Data Mongo, how would I proceed to do it?