# How to call default implementation in overriden spring-data method

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

First of all, this is *not a duplicate* of [Spring Data: Override save method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036159). I want to override the save method, and I know where to find the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations), but my question is how to call the original implementation in my custom code.

To override save() method in spring-data-*, you do something like below:

```
interface CustomizedSave<T> {
  <S extends T> S save(S entity);
}

class CustomizedSaveImpl<T> implements CustomizedSave<T> {

  public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    // Your custom implementation
  }
}

interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, CustomizedSave<User> {
}

interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>, CustomizedSave<Person> {
}
```

My question is how to call the "super" implementation of save()? In spring-data-elasticsearch, the default save() implementation is not so simple to set up (basically I need to copy AbstractElasticsearchRepository source code), so I would rather not do this.

Comment: In the code shown in the question, where should `super.save(...)` be called? Has an attempt been made to call `super.save(...)`? If not, what prevents it; if yes, what problem is being faced? The question seems unclear in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public User save(User entity) {
    JpaRepositoryFactory jrf = new JpaRepositoryFactory(em);
    UserRepositories repoWithoutCustom = jrf.getRepository(UserRepositories.class);
do somth....
}
```

Where `repoWithoutCustom` what you need, your `UserRepository` without any customized methods. Just use required `RepositoryFactory`, in your case Elastic as i understood

Comment: Your answer is about spring-data-jpa. I’m more interested in a generic solution for all spring-data flavours. In JPA, you simply call EntityManager.save(), but in spring-data-elasticsearch, it doesn’t seem that simple.

Comment: Did you trying : just create `new ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory(template)` (template is `ElasticsearchTemplate`) and getting required repository?