# QuerydslPredicateExecutor not having save() method

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I was trying to use `QuerydslJpaRepository` in my project, but it’s deprecated, and it is recommended to use `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` instead. However, `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` does not have the `save()` method, which is present in `QuerydslJpaRepository`.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository should extend not only `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`, but [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) which contains `save` method (inherited from [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true)).

```
public interface YourEntityRepository 
    extends JpaRepository<YourEntity, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<YourEntity> {
}
```

Comment: If my interface extends from QueryDslPredicateExecutor then i am getting 8 errors in my implementation class as such as  ->   The type must implement the inherited abstract method QuerydslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity>.findAll(OrderSpecifier<?>...) ...its for all finder, count and exits methods. I don't want to do that. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No need to implement repository. Spring implement it for you

Comment: I need to have an implementation class as i need some additional methods. I have use composition to have QueryDslPredicateExecutor  in my implementation class but it does not have save() method.

Comment: You can try to make your repository implementation extended from SimpleJpaRepository which implements JpaRepository

Comment: My implementation class already extends from some base class. Can i use both QueryDslPredicateExecutor and SimpleJpaRepository in my implementation class using composition and then use SimpleJpaRepository  for only save() operation? I am not sure if 2 repositories for same domain object will create any issue.

Comment: You 'd better use BaseRepository extends JpaRepository for every repository https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107526/spring-jpa-base-repository

Comment: If my BaseRepository extends from JpaRepository then will there be any issue of having two repositories for same entity. I.e my implementation class is also a repository and QueryDslPredicateExecutor is also present in the implementation class as member variable. Should i use JpaRepository without specifying entity class?

Comment: So now i have one interface extending from JpaRepository<YourEntity, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<YourEntity>. I am just autowiring this in my implementation class and keeping my custom interface as is. So i have two interfaces now. Does that look fine?

Comment: You should have one repository. It is complicated to explain how to do it using comments. You shoud ask another question providing your code. More info how to create custom repository here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html  **Chapter 1.3 Custom implementations for Spring Data repositories**

Comment: I have followed the accepted answer from the below post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa